# OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters() throws OracleException: ORA-06564: object does not exist

Tags: c#, oracle18c, system.data.oracleclient, enterprise-library-6

Using the OracleClient that comes with ADO.NET in .NET Framework, I'm trying to call `OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters()` method on a procedure in the database, but I keep getting an `OracleException` with the message: `ORA-06564: object CustOrdersOrders does not exist`, even though I created the procedure successfully. I'm more familiar with SQL Server, so perhaps I'm missing something here.

### SQL

file 1:

```sql
create or replace PACKAGE PKGENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE
IS
TYPE CURENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE IS REF CURSOR;
END PKGENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE;
/
```

file 2

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CustOrdersOrders"(VCUSTOMERID IN Orders.CustomerID%TYPE := 1, CUR_OUT OUT PKGENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE.CURENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE)
    AS

BEGIN
    OPEN cur_OUT FOR
    SELECT
        OrderID,
        OrderDate,
        RequiredDate,
        ShippedDate
    FROM Orders
    WHERE CustomerID = vCustomerId;
END;
/
```

Both these files were executed in SQL*Plus as `@"path\to\file1.sql"`.

### Code

This is using the Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block, which ultimately wraps the ADO.NET API.

```cs
DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory(...); //this gets a custom configuration source
Database db = factory.Create("OracleTest");
DbCommand storedProcedure = db.GetStoredProcCommand("CustOrdersOrders");
DbConnection connection = db.CreateConnection();
connection.Open();
storedProcedure.Connection = connection;
db.DiscoverParameters(storedProcedure); //this ultimately calls OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(), which throws the exception.
```

When I run direct SQL queries using the same connection, they succeed.

#### More Details

This is actually part of unit tests written for the Data Access Application Block, which I forked [here](https://github.com/tsahi/data-access-application-block) in an attempt to revive this library. That's why it's using the `System.Data.OracleClient` and not the ODP.NET. The entire set of tests at https://github.com/tsahi/data-access-application-block/blob/master/source/Tests/Oracle.Tests.VSTS/OracleParameterDiscoveryFixture.cs breaks in a similar way.

The tests are running on an Oracle Database XE I installed locally.

#### Update

Following question by @madreflection, yes, the following code runs correctly:

```cs
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("OracleTest");
string spName = "AddCountry";
DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(spName);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "vCountryCode", DbType.String);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "vCountryName", DbType.String);
db.SetParameterValue(dbCommand, "vCountryCode", "UK");
db.SetParameterValue(dbCommand, "vCountryName", "United Kingdom");

db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);

using (DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.Text, "select * from Country where CountryCode='UK'"))
{
    Assert.IsTrue(1 == ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("United Kingdom", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CountryName"].ToString().Trim());
}
```

where "AddCountry" is defined as

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADDCOUNTRY
(vCountryCode IN Country.CountryCode%TYPE,
 vCountryName IN Country.CountryName%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Country (CountryCode,CountryName)
    VALUES (vCountryCode,vCountryName);
END;
/
```

It's interesting to note, though, that in this case the `OracleDatabase` pointed by `db` has in it's packages list just `EntlibTest`, defined (if I understand correctly) by

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE EntlibTest AS

PROCEDURE GetProductDetailsById
(vProductID IN NUMBER,vProductName OUT VARCHAR2,vUnitPrice OUT NUMBER);

END EntlibTest;
/
```

and then there is another file defining the body of this procedure with

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY EntlibTest AS

PROCEDURE GetProductDetailsById
(vProductID IN NUMBER,vProductName OUT VARCHAR2,vUnitPrice OUT NUMBER)
AS

BEGIN
    SELECT ProductName,UnitPrice INTO vProductName,vUnitPrice FROM Products where ProductId = vProductId;
END;

END EntlibTest;
/
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem with procedures created the same way that don't use user-defined types like `<unspecified-user>.PKGENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE.CURENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE`?

Comment: @madreflection see update

Comment: Your example of code that works correctly doesn't use `db.DiscoverParameters` so you've introduced a new variable (test setup variable, not program identifier variable). Is the problem with `db.DiscoverParameters` or is it related to the user-defined type? You can't tell yet because you changed *both* aspects.  You need to isolate the problem by changing only one thing at a time and testing. Can you provide an example that calls `db.DiscoverParameters` and doesn't use a user-defined type?

Comment: @madreflection it's true that the working example doesn't use `db.DiscoverParameters`, but it does identify the procedure and executes it. I'll try to make a call to `db.DiscoverParameters` on a procedure without user defined types and see what happens.

Comment: I'll post a new question without the DAAB around it, to make it simpler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62732305/oraclecommandbuilder-deriveparameters-throws-oracleexception-ora-06564-objec