# OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters() throws OracleException: ORA-06564: object does not exist ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY"

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, oracle18c, system.data.oracleclient

Using the OracleClient that comes with ADO.NET in .NET Framework, I'm trying to call `OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters()` method on a procedure in the database, but I keep getting an `OracleException` with the message: `ORA-06564: object CustOrdersOrders does not exist`, even though I created the procedure successfully. I'm more familiar with SQL Server, so perhaps I'm missing something here.

### SQL

file 1.sql:

```sql
create or replace PACKAGE PKGENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE
IS
TYPE CURENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE IS REF CURSOR;
END PKGENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE;
/
```

file 2.prc:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CustOrdersOrders"(VCUSTOMERID IN Orders.CustomerID%TYPE := 1, CUR_OUT OUT PKGENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE.CURENTLIB_ARCHITECTURE)
    AS

BEGIN
    OPEN cur_OUT FOR
    SELECT
        OrderID,
        OrderDate,
        RequiredDate,
        ShippedDate
    FROM Orders
    WHERE CustomerID = vCustomerId;
END;
/
```

file 3.prc

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADDCOUNTRY
(vCountryCode IN Country.CountryCode%TYPE,
 vCountryName IN Country.CountryName%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Country (CountryCode,CountryName)
    VALUES (vCountryCode,vCountryName);
END;
/
```

All of these files were executed in SQL*Plus as `@"path\to\file1.sql"`.

### App.config

```xml
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleTest" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=xe)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xe)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id=SYSTEM;Password=oracle;" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

### Code

```cs
private DbConnection connection;
private OracleCommand command;

[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleTest"].ConnectionString;
    connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
    command = connection.CreateCommand() as OracleCommand;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    connection.Open();
}

[TestMethod]
public void DeriveParametersWithoutUserDefinedTypes()
{            
    command.CommandText = "AddCountry";
    OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, command.Parameters.Count); // fails because Count = 0
}

[TestMethod]
public void DeriveParametersWithUserDefinedTypes()
{
    command.CommandText = "CustOrdersOrders";
    OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command); //throws 'ORA-06564: object CustOrdersOrders does not exist\nORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 156\nORA-06512: at line 1'
    Assert.AreEqual(2, command.Parameters.Count);
}

[TestCleanup]
public void Cleanup()
{
    connection?.Dispose();
}
```

#### More Details

This is happening in a fork I made for the Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block [here](https://github.com/tsahi/data-access-application-block) in an attempt to revive this library. That's why it's using the `System.Data.OracleClient` and not the ODP.NET.

The tests are running on an Oracle Database XE I installed locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my *Oracle-ish* point of view, this was your huge mistake:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CustOrdersOrders"
                            -                -
                            these double quotes
```

Because, by default Oracle stores all object names into the dictionary in upper case, but you can reference it any way you want, e.g. `custordersorders`, `CUSTordERsordERS`, `CUSTORDERSORDERS`, `CustOrdersOrders` - no problem. But, if you enclose any name (procedure, table, column, ...) into double quotes, you **must** use double quotes any time you reference that object, enclosed into same double quotes and matching letter case exactly as you used it when creating that object.

So: either recreate the procedure as `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CustOrdersOrders` (which is what I'd suggest), or use double quotes.

Comment: That fixed the exception, thanks. But it still doesn't discover the parameters.